# Every weakly convergent sequence is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

Theorem: Every weakly convergent sequence in X is bounded.

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a weakly convergent sequence in X. Let $T_n \in X^{**}$ be defined by $T_n(\ell) = \ell(x_n)$ for all $\ell \in X^*$. Fix an $\ell \in X^*$. For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, since the sequence $\{\ell(x_n)\}$ is convergent, $\{T_n(\ell)\}$ is a bounded set. By Uniform Boundedness Principle $ \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|x_n\| = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|T_n\| < \infty,$ i.e. $\{x_n\}$ is bounded.

**My question is:** why $ \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|x_n\| = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|T_n\|$ ?

Comment: Because we even have $\lVert T_n\rVert = \lVert x_n\rVert$ for every $n$. The canonical map $X \to X^{\ast\ast}$ is an isometry.

Comment: Is it difficult to prove it?

Comment: No. It's the definition of the norms plus a small application of Hahn-Banach.

Comment: Is the answer in this topic what you mean: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793083/reflexive-normed-spaces-are-banach ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's the argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equality $\|x_n\|=\|T_n\|$ is an instance of the fact that the canonical embedding into the second dual [is an isometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/793083/).

See also [Weak convergence implies uniform boundedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/643786/) which is stated for $L^p$ but the proof works for all Banach spaces.

Answer (score 3):

One way to think about it is to recall the following 'duality property' for norms, which holds for any normed space $(X,\lVert{\cdot}\rVert)$:

$$ \forall x \in X: \lVert x \rVert = \sup_{\lVert f\rVert_*=1} \lvert f(x) \rvert $$

$$ \forall f \in X^*: \lVert f \rVert_* = \sup_{\lVert x\rVert =1} \lvert f(x) \rvert $$

where the second equality is almost a tautology, depending on your definition of the dual norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert_*$ and the first equality is a consequence of the Hahn-Banach Theorem and is a pretty easy exercise. From this, the fact that $\lVert T_x \rVert_{**} \equiv \lVert x \rVert$ is pretty obvious:
$$ \lVert T_x \rVert_{**} = \sup_{\Vert f \Vert_* = 1} \vert T_x(f) \vert = \sup_{\Vert f \Vert_* = 1} \vert x(f) \vert = \lVert x \rVert$$

Comment: small typo: in the last equation $x(f)$ should be $f(x)$