# Compact operator and dual space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A:Q\to Q^{*}$ be a bounded linear operator where $Q$ is a Banach space with dual $Q^{*}$. I have shown that for a sequence $\{\varphi_{n}\}$ in $Q$ with  $\varphi_{n}\rightharpoonup 0$ it follows that $$\|A\varphi_{n}\|_{Q^{*}}\to 0.$$ Can I conclude that $A$ is compact?

Comment: [Every weakly convergent sequence is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825790/every-weak-convergent-sequence-is-bounded), so the assumption $\|\varphi_n\|_Q\le C$ is superfluous.

Comment: What kind of properties do you want $Q$ to have? e.g. is it reflexive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without further assumptions on $Q$ you cannot conclude that $A$ is compact.

Consider the natural embedding $A: Q = \ell^1 \hookrightarrow Q^* = \ell^\infty$ given by $Ax = x$.

Recall that $Q = \ell^1$ has the schur property which means that weakly convergent sequences in $\ell^1$ are norm convergent. Since, for $x \in \ell^1$, $\|x\|_{\ell^\infty} \leq \|x\|_{\ell^1}$ this means that $A$ trivially satisfies your property. However $A$ is not compact since if $e^i$ is the element of $\ell^1$ with $1$ in the $i$-th place and $0$ elsewhere then $\{e^i\}_{i \geq 1}$ is a bounded set in $\ell^1$ but $\{Ae^i\}_{i \geq 1}$ has no convergent subsequence in $\ell^\infty$.

---

If you additionally assume that $Q$ is reflexive then the result is true.

In this case, every bounded sequence in $Q$ has a weakly convergent subsequence. Hence if $\varphi_n$ is a bounded sequence then there is a subsequence $\varphi_{n_k}$ such that $\varphi_{n_k} \rightharpoonup \varphi$. By applying your assumption to the sequence $\varphi_{n_k} - \varphi$ we see that $A\varphi_{n_k} \to A\varphi$ in the norm topology on $Q^*$. Hence $A\varphi_n$ has a norm convergent subsequence so $A$ is compact.

Comment: Thank you very much!